# initializing in loop array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create such array in loop

```
dataset: [
{
x: 0,
y: 0,
},
{
x: 1,
y: 0.993,
}
]
```

But this way is not correct.

```
var array =  new Array(10);
                   for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                        array[i].x = 1;
                        array[i].y = 2;
                    }
```

How I can initialize in correct way?

Comment: `array[i]` is `undefined`.

Comment: You need to initialize each individual member of `array` with `array[i] = {}` before assigning properties, or just object literal notation as you did in the first code block `array[i] = {x: 1, y: 2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments made by SLaks and squint are correct, so this answer is more of an explanation of why your code isn't working like you think it should, and an example of what you could do instead.

You created an array with room to hold 10 *things* but you didn't specify what those *things* were and so nothing is contained in the array.

```
var array =  new Array(10);
```

you can visualize your array like this: 
array = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,...

The array you created was just a container for 10 *things* not yet defined. When you tried to assign the 'x' and 'y' properties of the array elements, you were were trying to operate on something that did not exist. To get what you want, I suggest creating an object that has the properties you want, with initial values, and then use your loop to add the number of elements you want.

```
var array = [];
var arrayObject = {x:0,y:0};

for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
    array.push(arrayObject);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this job in one assignment line as follows;

```js
var dataSet = (new Array(10)).fill("initial y value").reduce((p,c,i) => p.concat({x:i,y:c}),[]);
console.log(dataSet);
```

I just couldn't figure what `y` values you would like to have so inserted the initial values of the array. Change them the way you like later. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `new Array(10)` with

`var array = Array.apply( {}, { length: 10 } ).map( function() { return {} });`

`new Array(10)` is creating an array like

```
[ undefined, undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]
```

So you are trying to assign `x` on `undefined`

If you tried

`new Array(10).map(function(){ return {}; })` it will not work either.

An es6 way to do it would be

```
Array.from(new Array(10), () => { return { x: 1, y: 2 }; })
```

Answer (score 0):

In **JavaScript** the `Array` acts different than in static-typed languages, so there's no need to initialize it with fixed length.

For **ECMAScript 6** specification and later:

```
var points = [].fill.call({ length: 5 }, {x: 1, y: 1});
```

It produces

```
[{x: 1, y: 1},
 {x: 1, y: 1},
 {x: 1, y: 1},
 {x: 1, y: 1},
 {x: 1, y: 1}]
```

To ensure old browsers' support use `for` loop:

```
var points = [{x: 1, y: 1}];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) points.push(points[0]);
```